# Arduino ethernet shield, on post LED will not turn on

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to turn the Arduino's LED pin 13 to HIGH on a form post. When I submit the form, nothing happens to the LED; it stays off. Am I missing something? I'm using [Webduino](https://code.google.com/p/webduino/) library.

```
void setup()
{
  // set LED to OUTPUT
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  webserver.begin();

  webserver.setDefaultCommand(&defaultCmd);
  webserver.addCommand("form", &formCmd);
}

void defaultCmd(WebServer &server, WebServer::ConnectionType type, char *url_tail, bool tail_complete)
{
  outputIndex(server, type);  
}

void outputIndex(WebServer &server, WebServer::ConnectionType type)
{
  P(htmlHead) =
    "<html><head><title>Door Manager</title></head><body>";

  server.httpSuccess();
  server.printP(htmlHead);

  server << "<form action='" PREFIX "/form' method='post'>";
  server << "<input type='submit' value='LED HIGH' /></form>";

  server << "</body></html>";
}

void formCmd(WebServer &server, WebServer::ConnectionType type, char *url_tail, bool tail_complete)
{
  // POST
  if (type == WebServer::POST)
  {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

    // redirect to GET to this same action
    server.httpSeeOther(PREFIX "/form");
  }
  else // GET
    outputIndex(server, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the Ethernet shield uses pins 13, 12, 11, as SPI . Also 10 and 4, to select SD or ethernet.

[Arduino PINs not behaving equaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453107/arduino-pins-not-behaving-equaly)